# программа работает по разному под linux и windows (C++)

Tags: c++

Есть небольшая программа, я использовал только стандартную библиотеку, но она по разному работает под linux и windows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

vector<string> parce(string s)
{
    string ts;
    vector<string> sv;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    {
        while (s[i] == ' ' &&  i < s.size()){ ++i;}
        if (s[i] == '\"')
        {
            ++i;
            while(s[i] != '\"' &&  i < s.size())
            {
            ts.push_back(s[i]);
            ++i;
            }
            sv.push_back(ts);
        } else {
        while (s[i] != ' ' &&  i < s.size())
        {
            ts.push_back(s[i]);
            ++i;
        } sv.push_back(ts);}
        ts.clear();

    }
 for(int i = 0; i < sv.size(); ++i)
        cout << "{" << sv[i] << sv[i].size() << "}" << endl;

    return sv;
}

int main() {
    ifstream uiFile;
    uiFile.open("ui.ui");
    string g;
    while (getline(uiFile, g))
        parce(g);
    return 0;
}
```

вот файл который читает

```
pic:
  name: "1.bmp"
  pos: 0 0
end
pic:
  name: "5.bmp"
  pos: 100 100
end
pic:
  name: "back.bmp"
  pos: 20 400
  action: load: "ui.ui"
end
```

Выдаёт в консоль какой то бред

```
5}ic:
{name4}
{data/splash11}
1}
4}nd
```

В Windows всё норм, ума не приложу что делать. Под Windows компилировал MinGW а под Linux g++

Comment: 1) Разные компиляторы пораждают разный код
2) Посмотрите кодировку файла, который читается. Windows и linux в этом плане могут по разному ее читать.

Comment: Я нуб в C++, но одно знаю точно : в win и в linux разные соглашения о концах строк, вы думали об этом?

Comment: Скомпилировал я ваш код и у меня все нормально. http://imgur.com/a/qlq5n. Насколько я понял, вы ищите символ `\` для поиска системных символов?

Comment: Компиляция была с под debag или relase?